# Chat transcripts still refer to SOIS, Inc

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

> site design / logo © 2011 stack overflow internet services, inc; legal

Just a small feeling that the company name has been changed. This appears on the side of all chat transcripts.

Comment: Odd, I don't see it .. could be the fastest `status-complete` in history?

Comment: @Tim Still see it—try [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1362939#1362939), bottom right corner

Comment: All I see is "All times are UTC" when logged in (as a moderator), same when trying incognito. Very strange.

Comment: @Tim It's below even that. Something in the HTML is preventing scrolling—check source code?

Comment: Indeed it is, saw it when viewing source.

Answer (score 5):

I blame Joel. He's the one who wanted that name change.